# Adding a Tabbed Pane to a Panel using Layout managers

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, jtabbedpane

I am simply trying to add a tabbed pane with 5 tabs onto a panel, although only the final tab (**tab e**) is being shown.

I am obviously doing something fundamentally wrong here, I have tried changing the layout manager of the Panel the tabbed pane is being added to but I don't think this is the problem. Any adivce would be helpful thanks!

Main Class Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Data Structures Program");

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(600, 600);
    GraphicPanel G = new GraphicPanel();
    frame.add(G.getPanel());
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Graphics Class

```
public class GraphicPanel {

    public JPanel topPanel;

    public GraphicPanel() {
        JPanel Panel = new JPanel();
        Panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));

        JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
        tabbedPane.addTab("a", Panel);
        tabbedPane.addTab("b", Panel);
        tabbedPane.addTab("c", Panel);
        tabbedPane.addTab("d", Panel );
        tabbedPane.addTab("e", Panel  );

        topPanel = new JPanel();
        topPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
        topPanel.add(tabbedPane);
    }

    public JPanel getPanel(){
        return topPanel;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you must creates new instance of `JPanel` if you want to show in `JTabbedPane`

try this code:

```
JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
tabbedPane.addTab("a", new Panel());
tabbedPane.addTab("b", new Panel());
tabbedPane.addTab("c", new Panel());
tabbedPane.addTab("d", new Panel());
tabbedPane.addTab("e", new Panel());
```

Comment: I would add : a component can only be at most at one place it the hierarchy.